# Calculating percent cover from shapefiles

Tags: r, gis, shapefile

I normally do not work with shapefiles, so I am a bit lost here. I have two shapefiles each with multiple objects. The first is a set of 32 polygons (each one is a plot). The second shapefile has >10,000 objects which represent vegetation clusters of different sizes within each plot. I am trying to figure out.

1)  How do I calculate percent cover of total vegetation cover within each site?

2)  What percentage of each the vegetation cover is less than 5 meters in area in each plot?

This is what my data looks like in ArcGIS for a single plot.

[image]

Comment: Frequently, with polygon files, the area is embedded in the shapefile itself. Please put your shapefiles online (Dropbox?) and post a link as an edit to your question.

Comment: This link will take you to the shapefiles in my dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wyokxximppexyb3/p7VC-pfF2E

Comment: Three more questions (sorry...): (1) When I do this, I get very low vegetation coverage (generally < 0.2%). Does that make sense?? (2) In the data section of your vegetation shapefile, there is an "Area" column. What are the units? (3) Also in the data section of the vegetation shapefile there is a column "FID_plots". Does this correspond to the plot ID in the plots shapefile?

Comment: @jlhoward; 0.2% cover does not add up. The units should all be in meters and the areas are all in meters squared. The Area refers to the size in sq. meters of each vegetation object. THE FID plots do not correspond to the plot ID in the plot shapefile. Thanks for your help in doing this..

Comment: OK. There is a column `LocCode` in the data section of both shapefiles. It seems like there is one `LocCode` for each plot polygon. Is this the field which associates vegetation objects with plot polygons? When I use this instead of `FID_plots`, I get coverage between 13 and 66%. Does that sound right?? BTW: The reason for all this back-and-forth is that I don't want to post an answer that is idiotic.

Comment: @jhoward; Thanks for checking with me, 13-66 sounds about right. LocCode should match up with FID_plots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will do what you want, I think.

NB: This uses the area information stored in the shapefile polygons (as explained below). It does *not* use the `Area` column in your vegetation shapefile data section. In most cases, your `Area` is identical to the area stored in the shapefile, but in some cases your `Area` is much larger. Since I don't know where your `Area` data came from, it seemed safer to use the information stored with the shapefile polygons.

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)

setwd("<directory containing all your shapefiles>")
plt.map <- readOGR(dsn=".",layer="plots")
veg.map <- readOGR(dsn=".",layer="veg_in_plots")
# associate LocCode with polygon IDs
plt.data <- cbind(id=rownames(plt.map@data), LocCode=plt.map@data$LocCode)
veg.data <- cbind(id=rownames(veg.map@data), LocCode=veg.map@data$LocCode)
# function to extract area from polygon data
get.area <- function(polygon) {
  row <- data.frame(id=polygon@ID, area=polygon@area, stringsAsFactors=F)
  return(row)
}
# area of each plot polygon
plt.areas <- do.call(rbind,lapply(plt.map@polygons, get.area))
plt.data  <- merge(plt.data,plt.areas, by="id")  # append area column to plt.data
# area of each vegetation polygon
veg.areas <- do.call(rbind,lapply(veg.map@polygons, get.area))
veg.data  <- merge(veg.data,veg.areas, by="id")  # append area column to veg.data
# total area of vegetation polygons by LocCode
veg.smry  <- aggregate(area~LocCode,data=veg.data,sum)
smry      <- merge(plt.data,veg.smry,by="LocCode")
smry$coverage <- with(smry,100*area.y/area.x)    # coverage percentage
# total area for vegetation object with A < 5 msq
veg.lt5   <- aggregate(area~LocCode,data=veg.data[veg.data$area<5,],sum)
smry      <- merge(smry, veg.lt5, by="LocCode") 
# fraction of covered area coming from veg. obj. with A < 5 msq
smry$pct.lt5 <- with(smry, 100*area/area.y)
```

Produces this:

```
# head(smry)
#   LocCode id   area.x   area.y coverage      area  pct.lt5
# 1       1  3 1165.916 259.2306 22.23408  60.98971 23.52720
# 2      10 11 1242.770 366.3222 29.47626  88.21827 24.08216
# 3      11 12 1181.366 213.2105 18.04779 129.21612 60.60496
# 4      12 13 1265.352 577.6037 45.64767 236.83946 41.00380
# 5      13 14 1230.662 226.2686 18.38593  48.09509 21.25575
# 6      14 15 1274.538 252.0577 19.77640  46.94874 18.62619
```

**Explanation:**

Shapefiles can be imported into R using `readOGR(...)` in the `rgdal` package. When importing a polygon shapefile, the result is a "SpatialPolygonDataFrame" object. These objects basically have two sections: a polygon section, which has the coordinates needed to plot each polygon, and a data section, which has data for each polygon (so, one row per polygon). If the shapefile is imported as, e.g., `map`,

```
map <- readOGR(dsn=".",layer="myShapeFile")
```

then the polygon and data sections can be accessed as `map@polygon` and `map@data`. It turns out that the polygon areas are stored in the polygon section. To get the areas, we define a function, `get.area(...)` that extracts the area and polygon ID from a polygon. Then we call that function for all polygons using `lapply(...)`, and bind all the returned values together row-wise using `rbind(...)`:

```
plt.areas <- do.call(rbind,lapply(plt.map@polygons, get.area))
veg.areas <- do.call(rbind,lapply(veg.map@polygons, get.area))
```

Now we need to associate vegetation areas with plot polygons. This is done through column `LocCode`, which is present in the data section of each shapefile. So we first associate polygon ID's with LocCode for both plots and vegetation areas:

```
plt.data <- cbind(id=rownames(plt.map@data), LocCode=plt.map@data$LocCode)
veg.data <- cbind(id=rownames(veg.map@data), LocCode=veg.map@data$LocCode)
```

Then we append the area column based on polygon ID:

```
plt.data  <- merge(plt.data,plt.areas, by="id")  # append area column to plt.data
veg.data  <- merge(veg.data,veg.areas, by="id")  # append area column to veg.data
```

Then we need to sum the vegetation areas by LocCode:

```
veg.smry  <- aggregate(area~LocCode,data=veg.data,sum)
```

And finally merge this with the plot polygon areas:

```
smry      <- merge(plt.data,veg.smry,by="LocCode")
```

In the `smry` dataframe, `area.x` is the area of the plot, and `area.y` is the total area covered by vegetation in that plot. Since, for both shapefiles, the projection is:

```
 +proj=utm +zone=13 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

the units are in meters and the areas are in msq. To determine how much of the vegetation is coming from areas < 5 msq, we total the vegetation areas with area < 5 and merge that result with `smry`:

```
veg.lt5   <- aggregate(area~LocCode,data=veg.data[veg.data$area<5,],sum)
smry      <- merge(smry, veg.lt5, by="LocCode")
```

Finally, with the data we have it's straightforward to render maps for each plot area:

```
cols   <- c("id","LocCode")
plt.df <- fortify(plt.map)
plt.df <- merge(plt.df,plt.data[cols],by="id")
veg.df <- fortify(veg.map)
veg.df <- merge(veg.df,veg.data[cols],by="id")
ggp <- ggplot(plt.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group))
ggp <- ggp + geom_path()
ggp <- ggp + geom_polygon(data=veg.df, fill="green")
ggp <- ggp + facet_wrap(~LocCode,scales="free")
ggp <- ggp + theme(axis.text=element_blank())
ggp <- ggp + labs(x="",y="")
ggp <- ggp + coord_fixed()
ggp
```

[image]